# Value of the measure fields changed values when using a calculated column as filter

Tags: powerbi, build-automation, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-filters

I have one date column and one Rawfield and three calculated measures. The new measure fields had correct values if I listed all date in the table. It is also correct if I manually use the basic filtering to select the desired date (Q4 for every year except the current quarter (Q3), or, another use case, Q3 in every year). We need this table with dynamic changes in the selected quarters - e.g. Q4 for other years except Q2 if the current quarter is Q2. Or, for the 2nd use case, Q2 every year if the current quarter is Q2.

I created two filter columns to achieve these two use cases
Use case 1
PYE_CURQT =
IF ('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date] = MAX('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date]), "Select",
IF (QUARTER('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date])=4,"Select",
"Don't Select"))
Use case 2
PYEQ_CURQT =
IF (QUARTER('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date])=QUARTER(MAX('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date])),"Select",
IF ('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date] = MAX('Example 2 filter issue'[Cycle_Date]), "Select",
"Don't Select"))

However, for the 1st use case, the current quarter value did not show in the visual and for 2nd use case, the value of each measure were changed to different value comparing to original.

Why I got wrong answers even I used the same source table, same calculated fields just an automatic filter? How to fix this issue?
Here is the link of the example pbix file
https://github.com/dgao95/Share-to-public/blob/main/Example%202%20Filter%20issue.pbix

Thanks very much!
DG